# How can i get the reviews in google maps via API

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I have an app where i show the user a qr code and when they scan the qr code it takes them to my google reviews page and what i want to do is if they comment on my reviews page i want to give them a gift in my app (%10 off, free gift basket etc.) i considered google places api but i dont know how i can verify the person that scans the qr code in my app is the same person who comments on my google reviews page or if there is a place in the api where it lets me search if the gmail that the person uses commented or not . You may be confused if so im sorry feel free to ask me any questions

Thank You

I went through some youtube tutorials but couldn't find anything